# Ребят подскажите почему цикл не останавливается?

Tags: python

```
mas=[]
while True:
    for x in range(0,100):
        c=x**2+156*x-2000
        mas.append(c)
        if c>=0:
            print(c,x)
            break
print(mas)
```

Comment: Потому что `while True`?

Comment: Зачем вам цикл while? Вы выходите только из цикла for а while так бесконечно и крутится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас два цикла. Внутренний останавливается. Внешний бесконечный. Вероятно, должно быть как-то так:

```
mas=[]
doLoop = True
while doLoop:
    for x in range(0,100):
        c=x**2+156*x-2000
        mas.append(c)
        if c>=0:
            print(c,x)
            doLoop = False
            break
print(mas)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Просто я думал,что команда break прерывает цикл while всегда.

Comment: @Александр команда break прерывает только ближайший цикл, а в вашем случае это `for`

Comment: Я бы даже сказал не ближайший а цикл в внутри которого вызван оператор прерывания

Comment: Теперь разобрался,благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Зачем там вообще `while` ?

```
mas=[]
for x in range(0,100):
    c=x**2+156*x-2000
    mas.append(c)
    if c>=0:
        print(c,x)
        break
print(mas)
```

Результат тот же.

Можно воспользоватся генератором:

```
new_list = [x**2+156*x-2000 for x in range(0, 100) if x**2+156*x-2000 <= 0]
print(new_list)
```

Результат:

> [-2000, -1843, -1684, -1523, -1360, -1195, -1028, -859, -688, -515,
>   -340, -163]

И еще. В вашем коде в список попадает:

> 16

Судя по вашему условию там должны быть только отрицательные значения. 
Но так как вы добавляете в список значение перед проверкой, туда попадает 16 и после этого цикл прерывается.

Поменяйте немного код. Вот так:

```
mas=[]
for x in range(0,100):
    c=x**2+156*x-2000
    if c>=0:
        print(c,x)
        break
    else:
        mas.append(c)
print(mas)
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, переделал.